# How to fetch source iproute(2.6.32.130) not patches

Tags: linux, package-management, rpm, source

I want to look at the source of below package.

```
[root@ovs-1 ~]# rpm -qa | grep iproute
iproute-2.6.32-130.el6ost.netns.3.x86_64
```

I tried to install the src rpm as below, it showing below error.

```
[root@ovs-1 ~]# ls
iproute-2.6.32-130.el6ost.netns.3.src.rpm  rpmbuild
[root@ovs-1 ~]# yum install iproute-2.6.32-130.el6ost.netns.3.src.rpm 
Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Install Process
Examining iproute-2.6.32-130.el6ost.netns.3.src.rpm: iproute-2.6.32-130.el6ost.netns.3.src
Cannot add package iproute-2.6.32-130.el6ost.netns.3.src.rpm to transaction. Not a compatible architecture: src
Error: Nothing to do
```

when I try to install using rpm, it installs bunch of patches. I want to look at the complete source. How Can I do that ?

```
[root@ovs-1 ~]# rpm -ivv  iproute-2.6.32-130.el6ost.netns.3.src.rpm 
D: ============== iproute-2.6.32-130.el6ost.netns.3.src.rpm
D: loading keyring from pubkeys in /var/lib/rpm/pubkeys/*.key
D: couldn't find any keys in /var/lib/rpm/pubkeys/*.key
D: loading keyring from rpmdb
D: opening  db environment /var/lib/rpm cdb:mpool:joinenv
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages rdonly mode=0x0
D: locked   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Name rdonly mode=0x0
D: Expected size:       485085 = lead(96)+sigs(1284)+pad(4)+data(483701)
D:   Actual size:       485085
warning: iproute-2.6.32-130.el6ost.netns.3.src.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID fd431d51: NOKEY
D:  added source package [0]
D: found 1 source and 0 binary packages
D: Expected size:       485085 = lead(96)+sigs(1284)+pad(4)+data(483701)
D:   Actual size:       485085
D: InstallSourcePackage at: psm.c:244: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID fd431d51: NOKEY
iproute-2.6.32-130.el6ost.netns.3
D: ========== Directories not explicitly included in package:
D:          0 /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/
D:          1 /root/rpmbuild/SPECS/
D: ==========
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
D: fini      100644  1 (   0,   0)      1355 /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/iproute-Makefile-RHEL-setting.patch;550875bf unknown
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
D: fini      100644  1 (   0,   0)     26348 /root/rpmbuild/SPECS/iproute.spec;550875bf unknown

[root@ovs-1 ~]# ls /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/
iproute2-2.6.25-segfault.patch
iproute2-2.6.29-IPPROTO_IP_for_SA.patch
iproute2-2.6.31-arpd_usage.patch
iproute2-2.6.31-fix-changing-of-ip6ip6-tunnel-parameters.patch
iproute2-2.6.31-lnstat-dump.patch
iproute2-2.6.31-lnstat-typo.patch
iproute2-2.6.31-ss_miss_parameter.patch
iproute2-2.6.31.tar.bz2
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not a 2.6.32 so must be a distro backport - why not got to the horse's mouth

http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/shemminger/iproute2.git/refs/